# Alerting for rapid disk growth

Tags: bash, file-system

I have a server that is pretty stable (disk capacity) until a certain event occurs and then the drive grows over the course of two days until it is full. I wrote a very simple bash script but I'm not too happy with parts of it. First, I want to be able to see the capacity as a percent down to the tenths place. Also, doing an evaluation I had to strip my value of any decimal places to compare it against my defined threshold. Lastly I feel that I made too much use of `cut` where I could've been more efficient. I'd love to get some tips for improvement.

```
#! /bin/bash

monDrive=/opt
prevReading=/root/diskcheckreading.txt
percentThreshold=1
emailAlert=alerts@domain.com

#Check if log file exists

if [ ! -f $prevReading ]
    then
        touch $prevReading
        prev=$(printf "%0.2f\n" $(bc -l <<< $(df /opt | grep opt | cut -d' ' -f24)/$(df /opt | grep opt | cut -d' ' -f23)*100))
        echo $prev > $prevReading

fi


#Get current percentage used of monitored drive
current=$(printf "%0.2f\n" $(bc -l <<< $(df /opt | grep opt | cut -d' ' -f24)/$(df /opt | grep opt | cut -d' ' -f23)*100))

#import previous reading
prev=$(cat $prevReading)

#Calculate the difference
results=$(bc -l <<< $current-$prev )

#Convert to percentage
results100=$(bc <<< $results*100)

#Remove any number after decimal place so that bash can evaluate
rescleanup=$(echo $results100 | cut -d'.' -f1)

#Convert to percentage
percentThreshold100=$(bc -l <<< $percentThreshold*100)

#Check if the difference exceeds the threshold
if  [ $rescleanup -gt $percentThreshold100 ]
     then printf "\"$monDrive\" has grown $results%% in the past hour.\n\n$(hostname):$(pwd)/$(basename $0)" | mail -s "Disk Alert - $(hostname):$monDrive" $emailAlert

fi

#log current reading for next check
emailecho $current > $prevReading
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the help received here, this is the updated version that is tested and working. Thanks for the help!

```
#!/bin/bash 

monDrive=/opt
prevReading=/root/diskcheckreading.txt
percentThreshold=1
emailAlert=alerts@domain.com

checkDiskUse() {
        df "$monDrive" | awk 'END{printf "%0.2f",$2/$1*100; exit}'
}

#Check if file exists with previous reading
[ -f $prevReading ] && prev=$(cat $prevReading) || { checkDiskUse > $prevReading; exit; }

#Validate file content
printf "%0.2f" "$prev" > /dev/null || exit

#Get current percentage used of monitored drive
current=$(checkDiskUse)

#Calculate the difference
results=$(bc -l <<< $current-$prev )

#Check if the difference exceeds the threshold
if  [[ $results > $percentThreshold ]]
     then printf "\"$monDrive\" has grown $results%% in the past hour.\n\n$(hostname):$(pwd)/$(basename $0)" | mail -s "Disk Alert - $(hostname):$monDrive" $emailAlert

fi

#log current reading for next check
echo $current > $prevReading
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Proceed when `prevReading` file does not exist?

   Your script proceeds to create the file first, and then *almost* immediately performs the same calculation. In this case, it might be better to just create the file first, `exit` from the script and then wait for its next invocation to do the comparison.
2. Performing the same calculation twice

   You are repeating the same commands for setting `prev` and `current`, so you should put it in a function:

   ```
   checkDiskUse() {
       df "$monDrive" | awk '/\'"$monDrive"'/{printf "%0.2f",$3/$2*100; exit}'
   }
   ```
3. `cut -d' ' -f23/24` can be substituted with `awk`

   As illustrated above, `awk` can 'solve' your weird usage of `cut`-ting on whitespaces, and then calling `bc` on them. Your use of `cut` assumes that the relevant line has your desired values (used / total) exactly `23` whitespaces before them, which may be wrong in the future. Let `awk` do the whitespace parsing for you instead, and simply extract the third and second values respectively (`$3`, `$2`).
4. Validate file contents

   It's good practice to sanity check that the file you are reading from has valid data. A simple way to do so is to check if `printf` is able to parse it correctly or not:

   ```
   printf "%0.2f" "$prev" > /dev/null || exit
   ```

   If the input value `$prev` is valid, `printf` returns with a successful exit code. Otherwise, the statement proceeds to the 'or' `||` part and `exit` the script as a fail-safe measure.
5. `[` vs `[[`

   As you have discovered, the basic test command `[` does not deal with decimal values, but `bash`'s built-in [`[[` conditional expression](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression) happens to handle that well. Compare:

   ```
   $ [ 0.601 -gt 0.6 ] && echo Y
   bash: [: 0.601: integer expression expected
   $ [[ 0.601 > 0.6 ]] && echo Y
   Y
   ```

---

To sum it up

```bash
monDrive=/opt
prevReading=/root/diskcheckreading.txt
percentThreshold=1
emailAlert=alerts@domain.com
checkDiskUse() {
    df "$monDrive" | awk '/\'"$monDrive"'/{printf "%0.2f",$3/$2*100; exit}'
}
[ -f $prevReading ] && prev=$(cat $prevReading) || { checkDiskUse > $prevReading; exit; }
printf "%0.2f" "$prev" > /dev/null || exit
current=$(checkDiskUse)
results=$(bc <<< "$current - $prev")
if [[ $results > $percentThreshold ]]
    then printf "\"$monDrive\" has grown $results%% in the past hour.\n\n$(hostname):$(pwd)/$(basename $0)" | \
        mail -s "Disk Alert - $(hostname):$monDrive" $emailAlert
fi
emailecho $current > $prevReading
```

Note: `$monDrive` is assumed to only contain `/` at the start, since only the first is escaped in the `awk` statement. Refer to comments for a somewhat hack-y workaround in `vim`'s syntax highlighting (YMMV). Alternatively, I think using `END` instead of the regex might work too:

```
df "$monDrive" | awk 'END{printf "%0.2f",$3/$2*100; exit}'
```

Comment: am reviewing and testing all of your suggestions. I am stuck on the awk one though. If I set a variable for "monDrive" and run your command, I get zero output back. What am I missing? And, thank you for the support here!

Comment: So it looks like this will work:
    df "$monDrive" | awk '/\'"$monDrive"'/{printf "%0.2f",$3/$2*100; exit}'

Comment: Ahh, so the output does not start with `/...`, my bad... edited as such.

Comment: THe code works great, and this is just a nuisance, but escaping the apostrophe causes VIM to incorrectly interpret the syntax, anyone know a workaround for this? See example [here](http://i.imgur.com/MKIYqhM.png)

Comment: A somewhat hack-y solution is to match just on the path without the starting `/`, then this might work: `awk "$monDrive"'/{printf ...'`. Effectively, we are using the starting `/` as the start of a regex expression for `awk`. Please test. :)

Answer (score 1):

- `bc` is an overkill. For simple calculations use arithmetic expansion, e.g.

  ```
  results = $(($current - $prev))
  ```
- `read` built-in is way more friendly than `grep`/`cut` combo:

  ```
  df /opt | (read; read fs blocks used available rest; compute_percentage $used $available)
  ```

Comment: My understanding is that bash doesn't support floating point, and since I am looking to get to the tenths place I had to rely on bc.

Comment: Multiply numerator by 100 perhaps?